# Wordpress get_user_option() That Starts With

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Is there a quick and easy way to get a user option from the usermeta table whose key starts with a string?

for example something to the equivalent of:

```
SELECT meta_value FROM usermeta WHERE meta_key LIKE 'StartString%'
```

Comment: What goes wrong with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the comparison in the meta query, like so;

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query(
    array(
        'key' => meta_key,
        'value' => 'StartString%',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  global $wpdb;

  $search = $wpdb->esc_like( "w" );
  $search = $search . '%';  

  $sql =    "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key LIKE %s";
  $sql = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $search, $search);

  $matching = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );   

 echo "<pre>"; print_r($matching);

?>
```